# How do I speed up PHP Array / List functions?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am reading a table from a MySQL database in PHP.  I fetch results one row at a time using fetch_assoc().  I find that while the fetch is fast, parsing the array into variables (using either the list() function or indexing the array) is really slow, even using SplFixedArray.  Here is the code with some timing metrics included:

```
$stupid = new SplFixedArray(15);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  $time_post = microtime(true);
  $exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
  $time_pre = $time_post;
  echo (' Row Fetch: ' . $exec_time . '<br><br>');

  $stupid = $row;

  list ($category, $entity, $link, $channel, $text_date, $description, $tempe, $printo, $web, $watchlisten,
    $location, $title, $by, $page, $eventdate) = $stupid;
  echo "<br><br>";

  $time_post = microtime(true);
  $exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
  $time_pre = $time_post;
  echo (' List parsing: ' . $exec_time . '<br><br>');
}
```

This results in the following output:

> Row Fetch: 0.013195037841797
>
> List parsing: 0.024664163589478
>
> Row Fetch: 1.5974044799805E-5
>
> List parsing: 0.016013860702515
>
> Row Fetch: 1.5020370483398E-5
>
> List parsing: 0.017437934875488
>
> Row Fetch: 1.9073486328125E-5
>
> List parsing: 0.019788026809692
>
> etc.

So every row fetch (after the first one) is very fast.  But every time I parse the array into variables, it's pretty slow especially since I'm processing thousands of records.

Any suggestions on how to speed this up?

Comment: Why are you doing the `list()`

Comment: ___parsing the array into variables (using either the list() function___ Is I would guess totally unnecessary. The values are already in an array so use them from there! That cuts out all the time consuming part of the code

Comment: just fetch all rows at once, or limit it to 200 rows and then fetch them all, then after fetching iterate them. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Are you sure you're calculating that execution time correctly? Looks terribly complicated and error prone… =_=

Comment: Another guess I would hazzard is you are doing the `list()` because you are doing a `SELECT *` if thats the case change the select to only select what you want and that will also speed up the fetching as well and remove the need for the `list()`

Comment: I am doing a `SELECT *` as you correctly guessed, but does it matter once the fetch is already done?

Comment: If you only want those specific columns then only select them. That means the database has to collect less data, less data has to be transfered over the network, and `$row` only contains those columns

Comment: FYI, the following code gives similar execution times: `$category = $row[Category]; $entity = $row[Entity]; $link = $row[Link]; $channel = $row[Channel]; $text_date = $row[Text_Date];
      $description = $row[Description]; $tempe = $row[Temp];$printo = $row[`Print`]; $web = $row[Web]; $watchlisten = $row[WatchListen];
      $location = $row[Location]; $title = $row[Title]; $by = $row[By]; $page = $row[Page]; $eventdate = $row[EventDate];`

Comment: @SteveSilberberg ,i think you don't need the line `$stupid=$row;` you could instead use directly `list ($category, $entity, $link, $channel, $text_date, $description, $tempe, $printo, $web, $watchlisten,
    $location, $title, $by, $page, $eventdate) = $row;` .You could also simply use the extract() function to make your code more clean.I think these few changes can help you make the parsing less slow.

Comment: @SteveSilberberg  this `echo (' Row Fetch: ' . $exec_time . '<br><br>');`  and  ` echo "<br><br>";` are also evaluated...The result could then be less biased if you put these lines out of the scope of the list structure evaluation...

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why this works, but it speeds up things to almost instantaneous:

```
  $everything = implode("|", $row);

  list ($category, $entity, $link, $channel, $text_date, $description, $tempe, 
  $printo, $web, $watchlisten, $location, $title, $by, $page, $eventdate) = 
            explode("|", $everything);
```

My guess is that the array $row contains elements of mixed type and parsing through them causes the system to bog down.  Once everything has been converted to a string and then put back into an array, it's really easy to assign the array elements.  Or at least that's my guess.